# JAVA HOME PATH correctly set in Environment but wrong when compiling via Node.js

Tags: java, cordova

I received this isue: `com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath. Oerhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`"

However, my JAVA HOME is set as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

With PATH

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

When node.js spawns a forked environment, it doesn't copy over your user's environment variables. You will need to do that manually.

You will need to get JAVA_HOME from process.env and set it in your exec() call. 
Something like this should work:

```
var config = {
    env: process.env
};
exec('javacmd', config,
    function() {
        console.log(arguments);
});
```

Or if you wanted to be more explicit, you could extract only the variables you needed (`JAVA_HOME`, etc) from `process.env`

See here for more details:

[How to exec in NodeJS using the user's environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020914/how-to-exec-in-nodejs-using-the-users-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall node js and re install node js. Its solve my problem.